# compare textfield input with string

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uitextfield

Could you please tell me why this code is not comparing the input text in the textfield with the "admin" string?

```
if ([usertext.text isEqualToString:@"admin"]) {                 
     if ([inputText length] <= 8) {
            return [self method2];
     }
     return [self method];
}
```

EDIT : Actual code

```
-(void)method1{ 
  NSString *usertext=[uname text]; 
  NSString *inputText = [typepassword text]; 

  if ([usertext isEqualToString:@"admin"]) { 
     if( [inputText length] <= 8 ) { 
        return [self method2]; 
     } 
     return [self method]; 
  } 
  moviesViewController *moviesViewcont = [[moviesViewController alloc] init]; 
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:moviesViewcont animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint (or NSLog) to the first `if` and check it the value for `usertext` is set.

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing up usertext and inputText? The actual CODE looks otherwise sound..

Comment: i have tried with usertext.text also but still it is showing error as  property text is not found on object type nsstring.i have declared it as a NSString *usertext=[uname text];

Comment: @LokeshReddy why did you try usertext.text? Do you even know which textfield represents the input?

Comment: this is the actuall thing im trying to excute                   -(void)method1{    
     NSString *usertext=[uname text];
     NSString *inputText = [typepassword text];
              if ([usertext isEqualToString:@"admin"]) 
        {         
            if( [inputText length] <= 8 )
           {
            return [self method2];
            }
            return [self method];
        }    
    moviesViewController *moviesViewcont = [[moviesViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:moviesViewcont animated:YES];
    
}

Comment: @LokeshReddy I edited the question with the code you put in comments. Don't post code in comments, edit your original question instead.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you never wired up your UITextFields in IB.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are trying to see if the word "admin" is contained in the input?

the method `isEqualToString:` makes an exact comparison, meaning the usertext.text needs to be exactly "admin" for that to be true.
Also, if that's true, then the string length will be 5, so checking for it to be shorter than 8 is unnecessary.

If you want to know if it's contained, you need to do this:

```
if ([usertext.text rangeOfString:@"admin"].location != NSNotFound) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No im taking admin as input still it in not comparing.if i use .text it is showing error as undefine

Comment: @ismael i have worked with you are code but still it is not working

Comment: Put some breakpoints and see where the problem is ... you are trying to find an answer in SO when it's something you should be able to debug easy enough

Comment: @Krishnabhadra im trying to login for same length strings only

Answer (score 0):

Your code does look good and error free. Some possible error reasons are

1. The `usertext` contains a string with spaces.

   In that case the comparison `isEqualToString` with "admin" will fail.
2. You are checking the wrong `UITextField`, or the variable `usertext`
   is `nil`.
3. You made a mistake thinking first condition fails. Have you did a debugging with breakpoints?

EDIT : put some NSLog statement before if condition

```
NSLog(@"Username text : %@",usertext); 
NSLog(@"password text : %@", inputText);
```

Comment: im trying to login for same length strings only –

Comment: @LokeshReddy put a break point before the first if condition, execute the code step by step. When you executing put the cursor over variable and see its current value, and check if they are the values you expecting..

Comment: it is checking only for password not for username textfield

Comment: You mean if you put a different username other than admin, the first condition is returning true?

Comment: yes .it is returning to method condition ..plz give a code to compare a textfield text and assign string tex

Comment: it is checking only for password text field for both condition whether it is wrong with my logic?

Comment: @LokeshReddy your code is fine.. I think you need to NSLog the texts you have before the if statement. Please see my edit